# Virus Detected Error after power interruption

Tags: ms-access

I am coordinator and using software at an academy. This software is developed using Microsoft Access application, but it has a major issue.

We are living in city where power interruption is as usual, and if power is interrupted while using this software, later after reopen computer, this application gives error of **Virus Detected** and doesn't work properly.

Q: Is it related to the Microsoft Access or developer has done something?

Comment: buy backup UPS could save you from loosing other data too!

Comment: No problem about purchasing UPS backup but I want to know why is it happening.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t believe that it would be related to Access. Can you open and run other databases on that computer? It is unusually for software to give some “virus” message – that usually the job of virus protection software, not that each program has its “own” ability to check for a virus.

Is the message coming from the computers virus protection system, or coming from the VBA code in the Access application?

You could certainly open up the Access application, and open any code module in design mode. You can then go edit->find

[image]

The above will search all code (including code in forms) for the text. If the text message is coming from your application, you would be able rather easy to find the text “Virus” in the software rather easy.

So a quick search of the code in the Access application should rather easy allow you to find that message in the VBA code.